# C# Equality check for generic wrapper with implicit cast doesn't work for classes

Tags: c#, generics, equality, implicit-conversion

So I have a generic wrapper class with an implicit cast like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    T _value;

    public Wrapper(T val)
    {
        _value = val;
    }

    static public implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
    {
        return wrapper._value;
    }

    // ... other functionality
}
```

When I use this for an int I can use `==` to check for equality.
However when I use it to wrap a class I can't:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int normalInt = 3;
    var wrappedInt = new Wrapper<int>(3);
    Console.WriteLine(wrappedInt == normalInt);

    SomeClass normalClass = new SomeClass();
    var wrappedClass = new Wrapper<SomeClass>(new SomeClass());
    Console.WriteLine(wrappedClass == normalClass); // implicit cast gives compile error
    Console.WriteLine((SomeClass)wrappedClass == normalClass); // explicit cast does work
}
```

I get the compile error (with the implicit cast):

```
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Wrapper<SomeClass>' and 'SomeClass'
```

However when I explicitly cast it does work...

Why does this happen?
And how can I fix this so that an explicit cast isn't needed?

Minimal working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZv9jI

Comment: @Blorgbeard It most certainly *does* cover why it works when using numeric types.

Comment: I think `int == double` is different to `Wrapper<int> == int`. There's no *standard* implicit conversion there.

Comment: @Blorgbeard There's no "predefined reference type equality operator" there either.

Comment: @IvanStoev Eric did, in the duplicate...

Comment: You can solve this calling `Equals`.

Comment: Eric's answer says exactly whats going on. In the case of `int` there is an overload of `==` that takes two `int`s therefore it succeeds.

Comment: @IvanStoev It was marked as a duplicate.  Blorgbeard reopened it.

Comment: @Inbetween Eric's explanation that "There is a standard implicit conversion from int to double and there is an equality operator that takes two doubles" doesn't appear to apply, because there is no standard implicit conversion.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Eric provides two reasons why the rule prohibiting the behavior doesn't apply.  There only needs to be one reason why the rule prohibiting the behavior doesn't apply for it to not apply.  In the case of this example, only one reason does apply, but that's still enough.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thats because I think (God help me) that Eric wasn't very precise. He first states that a *a user-defined conversion is by definition not a standard conversion*, therefore a conversion form `int` to `double` can't be a standard conversion because its user defined to begin with. I think he meant that there is an implicit conversion form int to double period.

Comment: This also works for string - even if you implement all the interfaces the base types have - it won't work. There simply seems to be a 'hack' somewhere in the complier that preforms implict converions for base type while using operator==

Comment: Having tracked down the spec and read the section myself, I think I understand now. The rule that requires *standard* implicit conversions applies to the standard *reference type* equality operator only. `int == Wrapper<int>` can resolve to the standard `int` equality operator instead, and the rule doesn't apply - so the custom conversion operator is fine. Eric's statement that "There is a standard implicit conversion from int to double" confused me, because I read it to mean that the conversion *had* to be standard.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It *does* have to be a standard implicit conversion operator.  *If you're using the predefined reference type equality operator*, which that code isn't.

Comment: @Servy yes, that is what I said. The quote "There is a standard implicit conversion from int to double and there is an equality operator that takes two doubles" is not about reference equality.